# Dnsmasq DNSSEC UDP issue on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 on Google Compute Engine. I have compiled the latest version of Dnsmasq (2.80) with the following configuration:

```
no-resolv
server=8.8.8.8
conf-file=/usr/share/dnsmasq-base/trust-anchors.conf
dnssec
port=5353
```

I then issue the following command:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 pir.org
```

After that there's a long pause, and the result comes back:

```
:~$ dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 pir.org
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 pir.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62921
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pir.org.                       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pir.org.                299     IN      A       97.107.141.235

;; Query time: 56 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#5353(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 15 00:55:35 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

Which indicates it is reverting to TCP mode.

dnsmasq log says:

```
dnsmasq: reducing DNS packet size for nameserver 8.8.8.8 to 1280
```

If I do the exact same thing on Amazon Web Services, dig returns immediately without resorting to TCP mode.

When 1.1.1.1 is used as an upstream server in dnsmasq on GCE, there is no long pause and nothing logged in the dnsmasq log. However, it is still reporting truncated result/TCP mode:

```
~$ dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 pir.org
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> @127.0.0.1 -p 5353 pir.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 61800
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pir.org.                       IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pir.org.                220     IN      A       97.107.141.235

;; Query time: 53 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#5353(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Aug 15 01:44:23 UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52
```

Packet capture (GCE):

```
03:39:06.405852 IP 10.154.0.29.32748 > 8.8.8.8.53: 53258+ [1au] A? pir.org. (48)
03:39:06.420540 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.154.0.29.32748: 53258$ 2/0/1 A 97.107.141.235, RRSIG (219)
03:39:06.420726 IP 10.154.0.29.14117 > 8.8.8.8.53: 46254+ [1au] DS? org. (32)
03:39:06.421028 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.154.0.29.14117: 46254$ 3/0/1 DS, DS, RRSIG (403)
03:39:06.421154 IP 10.154.0.29.8094 > 8.8.8.8.53: 56315+ [1au] DNSKEY? . (28)
03:39:06.422456 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.154.0.29.8094: 56315$ 3/0/1 DNSKEY, DNSKEY, RRSIG (864)
03:39:06.422995 IP 10.154.0.29.34809 > 8.8.8.8.53: 46400+ [1au] DS? pir.org. (36)
03:39:06.429627 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.154.0.29.34809: 46400$ 3/0/1 DS, DS, RRSIG (283)
03:39:06.429974 IP 10.154.0.29.26859 > 8.8.8.8.53: 55747+ [1au] DNSKEY? org. (32)
03:39:06.430307 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.154.0.29.26859: 55747$ 7/0/1 DNSKEY, DNSKEY, DNSKEY, DNSKEY, RRSIG, RRSIG[|domain]
03:39:11.405991 IP 10.154.0.29.26859 > 8.8.8.8.53: 55747+ [1au] DNSKEY? org. (32)
03:39:11.406544 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.154.0.29.26859: 55747| 0/0/1 (32)
```

Packet capture (AWS):

```
03:39:26.312403 IP 192.168.0.131.17535 > 8.8.8.8.53: 7225+ [1au] A? pir.org. (48)
03:39:26.327521 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.0.131.17535: 7225$ 2/0/1 A 97.107.141.235, RRSIG (219)
03:39:26.327571 IP 192.168.0.131.1520 > 8.8.8.8.53: 37804+ [1au] DS? org. (32)
03:39:26.329798 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.0.131.1520: 37804$ 3/0/1 DS, DS, RRSIG (403)
03:39:26.329893 IP 192.168.0.131.62316 > 8.8.8.8.53: 12792+ [1au] DNSKEY? . (28)
03:39:26.332070 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.0.131.62316: 12792$ 3/0/1 DNSKEY, DNSKEY, RRSIG (864)
```

Any ideas why GCE is behaving differently to AWS please?

Comment: Show the full output from dig. How big was the response? Was it actually more than 1280 bytes?

Comment: @zrm I've added in the full output of dig. Not sure where I see the response size?

Comment: It's the part that says "MSG SIZE  rcvd: 52", but that's too small to have legitimately been truncated.

Comment: @zrm maybe something on the GCP network interfering with the packets then? As I say, no issues with an identical setup on AWS.

Comment: 8.8.8.8 is Google anycast DNS. GCE may just be running their own instance of it which is configured differently than the one nearest AWS. What happens if you use 1.1.1.1?

Comment: @zrm I've added in information about 1.1.1.1 upstream for comparison. It's still resorting to TCP mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final query is small, but some of the intermediate queries necessary to validate DNSSEC are probably much larger. That's the nature of DNSSEC.

The original maximum UDP response size for DNS was 512 bytes, but DNSSEC responses can be several kilobytes. EDNS0 allows the client to advertise that it supports larger UDP responses, but a DNS server will have its own maximum UDP response size and may not support EDNS0 at all.

There are a lot of ways this can go wrong. Some older DNS servers don't support EDNS0 at all and if you send them a query with EDNS0 they silently drop the entire query. Some support it and allow responses large enough to cause the UDP packet to be fragmented, which can cause the response to disappear into a hole when there is a firewall that drops fragmented DNS responses, or the responses are sent with the don't-fragment bit set and then get discarded when they need to be fragmented.

What appears to be happening is that the initial response from 8.8.8.8 is getting dropped, causing dnsmasq to timeout and fallback to using a smaller (1280 byte) maximum which is then too small for the response and results in truncation and subsequent fallback to TCP. Whereas the responses from 1.1.1.1 are truncated from the beginning, perhaps because that server supports a smaller maximum UDP response size that doesn't result in fragmentation. You could verify this with a packet capture if you were so inclined.

Whereas with AWS, these DNS servers are all anycast, so the one responding (or the network between it and you) may be configured differently and support EDNS0 with a large enough UDP response size for the entire DNSSEC query response, and then that response is successfully delivered to the client.

The query response getting lost from 8.8.8.8 shouldn't be happening and there is likely some misconfiguration causing that, but seeing fallback to TCP for DNSSEC queries is not uncommon. It's the expected behavior when the response is larger than what the DNS server allows for UDP responses.

To avoid it you would either have to find a different recursive DNS server that allows larger UDP responses or run one yourself using e.g. Unbound, since dnsmasq doesn't support recursive DNS.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Your talk of packet capture sounds intriguing. Could you look at the tcpdumps I've just added? It looks to me like the first 6 lines of both are identical, but where AWS stops and returns the result, GCP keeps going. What's that about?

Comment: It's possible that the machine on AWS already has some of the records cached and doesn't need to look them up again. But you can also see where you're hitting the problem on GCP: It's the query for DNSKEY on org. If you check the response size for that (dig +dnssec org DNSKEY) it's 1625, which is the first query large enough to require packet fragmentation for UDP, and that's where it gets stuck.

Comment: Great! Your dig example allows me to replicate the issue without involving Dnsmasq whatsoever, i.e. (dig @ 8.8.8.8 +dnssec org DNSKEY) . When invoking that on AWS the query comes back in UDP with the result, but GCP comes back "connection timed out; no servers could be reached". (dig @ 1.1.1.1 +dnssec org DNSKEY) on GCP comes back quickly but in TCP mode/truncated, exactly the same behaviour as Dnsmasq. So it's a bad issue with GCP's network. (Space after @ added to avoid SF warning).